# saving text file in binary

Tags: c++, file, binary, save

I have a project witch I have to back up my text files in binary mode with the destination that is getting from the user. 
I was thinking to open my text files in binary and close them in the address that I have got from the user. but I don't know how to do that.

is there a way to close the files in a new address(saving them where ever I want) and not set an address directly because it's suppose to set by the user

Comment: nobody can answer my question? is a way to do that?

Comment: You could use [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) for saving data into binary file.

Comment: @vershov i have done that but i don't know how save my file

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code to save the file:

```
#include <fstream>
int main () {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);
    ofs << " data goes here";
    ofs.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The following is sample code to copy files:

```
ifstream source("from.txt", ios::binary);
ofstream dest("to.txt", ios::binary);

source.seekg(0, ios::end);
ifstream::pos_type size = source.tellg(); // file size
source.seekg(0);

char* buffer = new char[size]; // allocate memory for buffer

// copy file    
source.read(buffer, size);
dest.write(buffer, size);

// clean up
delete[] buffer;
source.close();
dest.close();
```

Comment: your code is useful, thank you. but i have to copy **some files** to **one file**, and with your code we can not save the address of saving file in the destination that the user tells us

Comment: @user2589043 the second snippet could be simple modified in order to merge several files into one as well as saving result file under different name. Also, you already have [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) to the description of the ofstream library, so you have all to do what you need.